# Date Picker jquery

Tags: jquery, error-handling, datepicker

```
<link href="css/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
```

I cant make the datepicker appear by clicking the textbox.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the jquery.ui library! :) for example

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```